# @OneToOne relationship with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a project for my University. It's a booking system like AirBnb. Inside the system there are two entities: Request and Structure. A Structure cannot be inserted without a relative Request. So I modelled Request in this way:

```
public class Request {
      //...attributes (with a Generated Id)..//

      @OneToOne(optional=false)
      @JoinColumn(
        name="structure_id", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
      private Structure structure;
}
```

And Structure:

```
public class Structure{
      //...attributes (with a Generated Id)..//
     private Request request;

     @OneToOne(optional=false, mappedBy="structure")
     public Request getRequest() {
     return request;
}
```

Each time I try to test the application, it fails during

> Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()

with this error message:

> Stacktrace:] with root cause
>    org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.Structure, at table: Request, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(structure)]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:396)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:369)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:529)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>       at it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.JPAInitializer.(JPAInitializer.java:25)
>       at it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.JPAInitializer.getEntityManager(JPAInitializer.java:43)
>       at it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.CatalogueDAO.saveRequest(CatalogueDAO.java:26)
>       at it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.view.SearchBean.validate(SearchBean.java:79)
>       at org.apache.jsp.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:134)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It's unable to map such relationship inside the DB? (MySQL 5.7.10 on Windows 10)
Request cannot live without a Structure and viceversa.
How can I solve it? 
Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT 1: 
I got this new error now:

> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.Structure.request -> it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.Request

Is this code right? Request should save the structure linked to it, right?

```
    Address address = new Address(//some fields//);
    Structure structure = new Structure(/*a name*/,address);
    Request request = new Request(structure);
    CatalogueDAO catalogueDAO = new CatalogueDAO();
    catalogueDAO.saveRequest(request);
```

EDIT 2:

The previous problem is solved by adding `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on the @OneToOne on Request.structure

But now I got this:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`notti_tranquille`.`request`, CONSTRAINT `FKbi1rasm9sdgrouh2mdklvi2q`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `structure` (`address_id`))

Structure has another attribute: Address, with its own Id and simple attributes

```
@OneToOne @MapsId
private Address address;
```

But If I check the tables created by JPA I see that the table structure has as primary key address_id... why?

Comment: em.persist(Request) will save the Structure if cascade is enabled. If not then you call em.persist(Request) and em.persist(Structure) ... just like JPA tutorials say

Comment: Yeah you are right! And I have to enable cascade for Address too. But address_id is still the Primary key of structure...

Comment: I made it! I deleted the `@JoinColumn` as Sergei said, and the `@MapsId` from Address. Also I added inside the constructor of Request the line: structure.setRequest(this). Now it all works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Why is annotation above getRequest()? Try do this

```
public class Structure{
  //...attributes (with a Generated Id)..//
@OneToOne(optional=false, mappedBy="structure")
 private Request request;


 public Request getRequest() {
 return request;
```

}

Did you try to delete  this annotation    @JoinColumn(
        name="structure_id", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false) .
Here you can find work example [one to one example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: I copied the documentation example (That you can find using Ctrl+Q on the @OneToOne annotations inside IntelliJ IDEA 15)

Comment: I tried and the result is this one: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.Request.structure in mappedBy of it.ispw.efco.nottitranquille.model.Structure.request`

Comment: in JPA you can annotate a field OR a property (getter), so this is not an issue